# Linking error: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::open(std::string const&)`

Tags: opencv, linker, mingw, video-capture

I'm trying to use an `.avi` file as my source. (Camera capture already works.) My project compiles without problems, but during linking I get the error:

`undefined reference to 'cv::VideoCapture::open(std::string const&)'`

What should I do? In which library is this `std::string` overload of `VideoCapture::open()` put?

***Edit:*** `VideoCapture(0)` (camera capture) compiles, links and works, so `VideoCapture(std::string)` has to be somewhere else that in libs I'm already linking with... right?

***Edit:*** `OpenCV` version: `2.4.9` (cloned from git yesterday).

Comment: Did you try to use the constructor ? VideoCapture(const string& filename);
Moreover, could you paste your code ?

Comment: @Poko, the problem was caused by me using `2.4.5` header files... A stupid mistake. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by me using `2.4.5` header files for `2.4.9` version.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more, how you were able to solve the error. I have alot of errors listed here--> http://pastebin.com/36y7f9VR , my opencv is 2.4.6 and the code is https://github.com/zafrullahsyed/videorecording/blob/master/videorecording.cpp

Comment: @ZafrullahSyed, check if you #include headers from the same version that you're linking to. If that's not it, then I don't know.

Comment: FYI. I recently upgraded an older app from OpenCV 2.4.x to the new 3.0.0 alpha release and got this same error. To fix I needed to link with (what seems a new separate video lib) opencv_videoio. It would appear this was part of opencv_video in the past.

Comment: @wezside thank you! i have just installed version 3, and that cut it :)